# Pandas join does not retain key fields from both dataframes

Tags: pandas

I have two dataframes and I am joining them like this:

```
merged=prvmthfile.merge(curmthfile, how='outer',on=['CUSTID','CTYPE'],suffixes=['prv','cur'],indicator=True)
```

Now, it adds the _prv and _cur to the common fields in the dataframes except the key fields CUSTID,CTYPE.
In the final output, I only see one set of CUSTId,CTYPE, is there a way to have CUSTID_prv,CUSTID_cur and CTYPE_prv,CTYPE_Cur?

Answer (score 0):

Probably just add the suffixes before merging and then change the merge keys and remove the `suffix` argument:

```
prvmthfile.add_suffix('_prv').merge(
    curmthfile.add_suffix('_cur'), 
    how='outer',
    left_on=['CUSTID_prv', 'CTYPE_prv'], 
    right_on=['CUSTID_cur', 'CTYPE_cur'],
    indicator=True)
```

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3,4,5],
                   'val': [1,2,3,4,5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,4,5,6],
                   'val': [11,22,33,44,55]})

df.add_suffix('_prv').merge(df2.add_suffix('_cur'),
                           how='outer', 
                           left_on=['id_prv'], 
                           right_on=['id_cur'],
                           indicator=True)
```

Output:

```
   id_prv  val_prv   id_cur val_cur      _merge
0      1.0     1.0      1.0    11.0        both
1      2.0     2.0      2.0    22.0        both
2      3.0     3.0      NaN     NaN   left_only
3      4.0     4.0      4.0    33.0        both
4      5.0     5.0      5.0    44.0        both
5      NaN     NaN      6.0    55.0  right_only
```